# Why are we not concerned about the distribution of the $x_t$ in an AR(1) model?

Tags: distributions, model, autoregressive

I am trying to investigate the reasons why we don't bother about the distribution of the $x_t$ in an autoregressive model.

Why do we concern ourselves about the distribution of $e_t$?
And why are the assumptions meant for $e_t$ alone knowing well that $e_t$ is as a result of $x_t-x_t^{estimated}$?

Comment: Of course the distribution of $\epsilon$ depends on the distribution of $x$, but the estimation problem is formulated directly from the errors, that's the reason.

Comment: @Firebug, since $x$ is a weighted combination of the current and past errors as per ChristophHanck's answer, of course there is a link between their distributions. However, it is helpful to think that an error $\varepsilon_t$ happens first and then it is used to generate the $x_t$, so the causality is from $\varepsilon_t$ to $x$ rather than the other way around. Saying that the distribution of $\varepsilon_t$ depends on that of $x_t$ is like saying (wrongly) that the electrical resistence *depends* on the voltage and the current strength. It is true that $R=V/I$, but this is not causal.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from $x_t-\hat x_t$ is not how we build the statistical theory around this model.
(This is also characteristic to a much broader class of statistical models than just the AR(1).)

The AR(1) model for a time series process $x_t$ specifies that 
$$
x_t=\varphi x_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t
$$
with $\varepsilon_t \sim i.i.d.(0,\sigma^2)$ and $\varepsilon_t$ being uncorrelated with $x_{t-1}$. Note that the distribution of $x_t$ is not specified in this definition.

Given the definition, we can derive properties of $x_t$ as a process; properties of estimators of $\varphi$ and $\sigma^2$; and properties of some test statistics based on the latter estimators, e.g. a test that $H_0\colon\ \varphi=0$.

- To derive the maximum likelihood estimator, we need to know or assume the distribution of $\varepsilon_t$.
- To derive the conditional least squares estimator we do not need a distributional assumption on $\varepsilon_t$.
- Whatever the estimator (maximum likelihood, conditional least squares, ...), we need to know or assume the distribution of $\varepsilon_t$ to derive finite-sample properties of the estimator of $\varphi$ and test statistics based on the estimators.

In any of these cases, the distribution of $x_t$ is irrelevant for the statistical theory around the model. In the derivations of the maximum likelihood estimator or the test statistics, the distribution of $x_t$ either plays no role or if it does, it cancels out in the final result. So it is simply irrelevant.

P.S. Note that there is a difference between the error (or shock, or innovation) $\varepsilon_t$ and the model residual $\hat\varepsilon_t:=x_t-\hat x_t$. We make assumptions on the former, not the latter.

Comment: "In any of these cases, the distribution of Xt is irrelevant for the statistical theory around the model".
with respect to the quote, This is my question why is the distribution of Xt irrelevant and in what situation will it be relevant. 
thank you.

Comment: @A.adedayo, If there was a reason why the distribution of $x_t$ were relevant, I would give it here. But since there is no reason, there is nothing to give. It is a little bit like asking, why is a degree in physics irrelevant for obtaining a job as a professor of the English literature. The only natural answer is, IMHO, "Why would you think it should be relevant?"

Comment: @A.adedayo, I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 1):

Next to the +1 answer by @RichardHardy, note that recursively solving for $x_{t-j}$ yields the so-called $MA(\infty)$-representation
\begin{eqnarray}
x_t&=&\epsilon_t+\varphi(\varphi x_{t-2}+\epsilon_{t-1}) \notag\\
&=&\epsilon_t+\varphi\epsilon_{t-1} +\varphi^2 x_{t-2}\notag\\
&=&\epsilon_t+\varphi\epsilon_{t-1}+\varphi^2\epsilon_{t-2} +\ldots+\varphi^j\epsilon_{t-j}+\varphi^{j+1} x_{t-j-1}
\end{eqnarray}
If $|\varphi|<1$ $\varphi^{j+1} x_{t-j-1}$ will vanish (in a suitable sense) as $j\to\infty$, such that
$$
x_t=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\varphi^j\epsilon_{t-j}
$$
Hence, $x_t$ is a function of present and past $\epsilon_t$, such that there is no need to specify any distributional properties of $x_t$ over and above those for (if any) $\epsilon_t$.

That said, even in "standard" regression models in which such recursive substitution of the regressors is not possible, we are typically interested in, for example, the conditional mean $E(y|X)$ so that we do not care about the marginal distribution of the regressors.

Comment: what happens if we decide to find the distributional properties of Xt. I read in an article that it will help in better forecast, how true is this. thanks

Comment: I do not know that article. As we try to explain, the distributional properties of $x_t$ follow from those of $\epsilon_t$. Indeed, if we know something about the latter, that may aid in constructing more precise *forecast intervals*.