# VAR model: compute covariance matrix

Tags: time-series, self-study, covariance-matrix, vector-autoregression

The following is an assignment, I just need some help understanding what I've done so far.

Suppose $X_1 \sim N(0, \sigma^2 / (1-\rho^2))$ and $U_2, \dots, U_n \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$, independent between them and with $X_1$. We define:

$$ X_k = U_k + \rho X_{k-1},$$

for $k=2,\dots,n$.

1. Show using induction that $(X_{k-1}, X_k)$ follow a bivariate normal.
   I used the equation:

$$(X_{k-1}, X_k) =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
\rho & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
X_{k-1}\\
U_k
\end{bmatrix}.$$
For the base case I used $k=2$:
$$(X_1, X_2) =
\begin{bmatrix}
X_1\\
U_{2}+\rho X_1
\end{bmatrix},$$
I have already proved that $U_{k+1}+\rho X_k$ follows $N(0, \sigma^2 / (1-\rho^2))$ using induction.

For the induction step I assume it holds for $k$ and we want to prove it holds also for $k+1$:
$$(X_k, X_{k+1}) =
\begin{bmatrix}
X_k\\
U_{k+1}+\rho X_k
\end{bmatrix},$$
which, as said before, I have already proved.

2. Compute the covariance matrix of $(X_{k-1}, X_k)$
   For the main diagonal I guess we can simply take the variance of the normal distributions: $\sigma^2 / (1-\rho^2)$.
   For the covariance I used the following equality:

$$2Cov(X_{k-1}, X_k) = Var(X_{k-1} + X_k) - Var(X_{k-1}) - Var(X_k).$$

This gives me that $Cov(X_{k-1}, X_k) = 0$.

3. Compute $Cov(X_{k-j}, X_k)$ for $k=2,\dots,n$ and $j=1,\dots,k-1$ using the model for $X_k$.

Basically I computed just $E[X_{k-j}X_k]$. Suppose I compute $Cov(X_{k-1}, X_k)$:

$$ E[(U_k + \rho X_{k-1})(U_{k-1} + \rho X_{k-2})]
= E[U_k]E[U_{k-1}] + \rho E[U_k]E[X_{k-2}] + \rho E[U_{k-1}X_{k-1}] + \rho^2 E[X_{k-1}X_{k-2}] = \rho^3E[X_{k-1}X_{k-2}] = \dots.$$

Is this sufficient?

4. Compute the covariance matrix of $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$. For this I need a suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: The first equation (Point 1.) is given in the assignment.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are not considering a VAR model, but a univariate AR(1) process. This may help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310518/acf-of-ar1-model-derivation https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285283/why-are-we-not-concerned-about-the-distribution-of-the-x-t-in-an-ar1-model/285299#285299